# How to keep model fixed during training?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to implement a model that uses encoding from multiple pre-trained BERT models on different datasets and gets a combined representation using a fully-connected layer. In this, I want that BERT models should remain fixed and only fully-connected layers should get trained. Is it possible to achieve this in huggingface-transformers? I don't see any flag which allows me to do that.

PS: I don't want to go by the way of dumping the encoding of inputs for each BERT model and use them as inputs.

Comment: Are you looking for a pre-defined class in Hugginface that allows you to do this; i.e., getting combined representation of your provided inputs? You might know about `BertModel` class, but your last PS made me hesitant to post the answer.

Comment: Not sure if I really get what you are trying to do, but can't you simply not use this parameters for the optimizer?

Comment: Yes, I tried the same thing and it is working well. Thanks @cronoik.

Comment: Would be great if you could submit an answer by your own to make this question useful for others.

Comment: Sure cronoik! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this is to just exclude the parameters related to the BERT model while passing to the optimizer.

```py
param_optimizer = [x for x in param_optimizer if 'bert' not in x[0]]
optimizer = AdamW(param_optimizer, lr)
```